# *ngFor ionic and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using this code to open import some cards from db with HttpClient in Ionic. I want after clicking on 1 card to open a details page with information according to the page. this info are in a db.

this is my html:

```
<ion-grid >
      <ion-row >
        <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of data; " [routerLink]="['/', 'main', item.imdbID]" >
         <ion-card button >
          <img src="{{item.img_dir}}" alt="">            
          <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: black;">
            {{item.cname}}</p>
            <!-- <p>{{item.description}}</p> -->
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

With this code I generate the cards. This is working.

This is my main.ts:

```
export class MainPage implements OnInit {

  data: any;

 constructor(public http: HttpClient, public navCtrl: NavController) { }


  ngOnInit() {

     fetch('http://192.168.1.88/Main/getDrinks').then(res => res.json())
     .then(json => {
       this.data = json;
     });

  }

}
```

With this I can open a page if I click on 1 card but i do not know how to import the details for that specific page.

Comment: what do you mean import details for that specific page????

Comment: if i click on a card, a detailsPage is open for a drink. In this this page i want to retrieve from db with {{item.description}} the details of that drink. i think i need to put the id of the drink and to import after id but I do not know how

Comment: i have done it in angular..if u are using angular you i can help u.

Comment: yes please. I'm using angular

Comment: The details are in your data variable?

Comment: details are in database. I want after I open a details page to get details from db with something like {{item.details}}.

Comment: data variable holds the details

Comment: Nobody? Any ideas?